# Measurable functions question.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$(X,\Phi_X)$ is a measurable space and $f:X\to Y$ is a measurable.
$\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{P}(Y)$ such that $f^{-1}(E)\in\Phi_X~\forall E\in\mathcal{A}$.

I have to show that $f^{-1}(F)\in\Phi_x\quad\forall F\in\Phi_\mathcal{A}$.

So far this is what I could prove:

$\Phi_\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that $\mathcal{A}\subset\Phi_\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}\subset\Phi~\forall \Phi$ $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{A}$.

We can distinguish two cases. If $F\in\mathcal{A}\subset\Phi_\mathcal{A}$ it is trivial. If $F\in\Phi_\mathcal{A}\setminus \mathcal{A}$, then we can write every element of $\Phi_A$ as countable unions/intersections of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ and we know preimages of the union/intersection is the union/intersection of preimage.

However, I feel that if there is a gap in that last paragraph, is it true that any element can be written in terms of countable unions and/or intersections? When I think about the complement of a set, I'm not sure if I can write it like that. If $f$ is not measurable, how can I guarantee that the complements of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are in $\Phi_X$?

**Edit:** if $F$ is the complement of a set $E\in\mathcal{A}$, then $f^{-1}(F)=f^{-1}(\mathcal{C}E)=\mathcal{C}f^{-1}(E)\in\Phi_X$ and we are done, right?

Comment: I find the notation unusual. However; hint: note $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \{E\in\Phi_\mathcal{A}:f^{-1}(E)\in \Phi_X\}\subseteq \Phi_\mathcal{A}$ and argue that $\{E\in\Phi_\mathcal{A}:f^{-1}(E)\in \Phi_X\}=\Phi_\mathcal{A}$ to conclude.

Comment: Thank you. However, that is what I don't know how to prove esentially.

Comment: You can conclude if $\{E \in \Phi_A:f^{-1}(E)\in \Phi_X\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Check the three properties.

Comment: If that set is a $\sigma$-algebra, then the pre-image of a set $E\in\Phi_A$ is indeed in $\Phi_X$ since $\mathcal{A}$ generates it (that's why that hypothesis is important) and we are done. Did I understand well?

Comment: If $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are two families of subsets of $Y$ s.t. $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$, then $\Phi_\mathcal{A}\subseteq \Phi_\mathcal{B}$. Furthermore, if $\mathcal{B}$ is already a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\Phi_\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$. Additionally, if $\Phi_\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{B}\subseteq \Phi_\mathcal{A}$ then $\mathcal{B}= \Phi_\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Thanks you! I think I'm kinda getting it.